# omitting the null string terminator in c++ string

Tags: c++, string, md5

In my little project, I am trying to hash some bitmaps and the bitmaps are like: "BMP1 /0 *bitmap data*". I am using a md5 hash library that I found on the internet and it works as simple as:

```
std::string md5(const std::string);
```

The problem is, since I have a string terminator in the middle of the memory, if I try to make a string from this memory, I can have only the first part and not the bitmap data. So, my question is, can I not finish the string here and take the whole data into it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead.

Comment: `std::string` *can* contain NUL bytes. `char*` cannot. To construct a `std::string` from a `char` buffer containing NUL bytes, use [constructor 4 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). Not sure if that is actually what you are asking though, can you add more detail? That said, πάντα ῥεῖ is probably right, an md5 is not really a textual string, more an array of bytes, so `std::vector` is probably a better match.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try to use the number 4 constructor anyways but I also will look up to the vector thing.

Comment: Thanks again, I did it with your help.

Comment: I think the hash library designer has just chosen the wrong interface for the function. A non-reference `const` argument already looks suspicious. And a `std::string` argument is not suitable for generic binary data. It should be `std::string md5(std::vector<char> const& data)`, unless the library wants you to hash only plain ASCII text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [constructors that `std::string` provides](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), you'll find that among the many constructors, besides the constructor that takes a null terminated string as an argument (5), there is a constructor that takes pointer to a character string, and a count of characters (4). The description mentions specifically that the pointed string may contain null characters. This means that the null characers do not terminate the string.